# Extracting values and formatting XML feed Rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, ruby-on-rails-3, nokogiri

I've got the following feed from an external site which I've brought in to my rails3.2 app via httparty.

It would seem I'm having a retarted moment and cannot figure out how on earth to format / style it. Do I need to use nokogiri or is it simpler?

```
["radcheck", [{"attribute_name"=>"User-Password", "batch_user_id"=>nil, "id"=>22, "op"=>":=", "radcheck_serial"=>nil, "raduser_id"=>nil, "username"=>"simon", "value"=>"pass"}, {"attribute_name"=>"User-Password", "batch_user_id"=>nil, "id"=>23, "op"=>":=", "radcheck_serial"=>nil, "raduser_id"=>nil, "username"=>"silver", "value"=>"rain"}.....
```

Comment: What you're showing is a ruby data structure, no need for nokogiri.  But what are you trying to accomplish, just render an html view for that data?  How about a rails view or partial?

Comment: Think I'm experiencing writers block... Am just trying to format with plain old html.. Don't seem to be able to loop through the values as usual.

Comment: Btw. Am pretty sure that's not standard ror output considering it's pulling from xml feed and output is different.

Comment: Can you add more details / code on how you retrieve your feed object ?

Comment: According to HTTParty doc, your comment is not correct : HTTParty parse automatically XML into a standard ruby hash...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your sample data:

```
feed = ["radcheck", [
  {"attribute_name"=>"User-Password", "batch_user_id"=>nil, "id"=>22, "op"=>":=", "radcheck_serial"=>nil, "raduser_id"=>nil, "username"=>"simon", "value"=>"pass"},
  {"attribute_name"=>"User-Password", "batch_user_id"=>nil, "id"=>23, "op"=>":=", "radcheck_serial"=>nil, "raduser_id"=>nil, "username"=>"silver", "value"=>"rain"}
]]

if feed.is_a? Array && feed.size >= 2
  radcheck = feed.first  # do you need this first element?
  data = feed[1]
  # now you have an array in data, and can loop over each hash
  Array(data).each do |elem|
    puts elem["id"] # and so on
  end
end
```

This works in my console, so you should be able to adapt this for your templating mechanism.

Comment: That makes more sense. However, in my console it gives me a TypeError: class or module required.

Comment: at which line does it give the error?  And what type is the object it's throwing the error on?

Answer (score 1):

Hum I think all you have to do is to loop over the 2nd element, which is an array of hash :

In controller :

```
@feed = ... # Retrieve your feed with httparty or other
```

In view :

```
<p>
First element: <%= @feed[0] #="radcheck", don't know the meaning of this %>
</p>
<p>
Attributes:
<ul>
<% @feed[1].each do |item| %>
  <li>
  Name: <%= item.attribute_name %><br />
  Batch User ID: <%= item.batch_user_id %><br />
  ID: <%= item.id %><br />
  OP: <%= item.op %><br />
  ... and so on ...
  </li>
<% end %>
</ul>
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for response. That method gives me the following error: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Comment: If `@feed` is exactly what you say (`["radcheck, [{ ...},{...}..."`), `@feed[1]` can't be `nil` and is an `Array` of `Hash`. This work in my console.

Comment: Got it working a slightly different way. Thanks for the help though - very helpful.